# jQuery AJAX get value from .each function and send it to AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How to set jQuery AJAX outside .each on my script below?

```
$('#btnUpdate').click(function()
{
    $('#result').html('');
    $('.moduleIDInput').each(function()
    {
        var uid = $(this).attr('id');
        var moduleID = $(this).val();

        var chk = new Array();

        $('#result').append('<h3>' +$(this).val() + '</h3>');

        $('input[data-uid=' + uid + ']:checked').each(function()
        {
            chk.push($(this).val());

            $('#result').append('<div>'+ $(this).val() + '</div>');
        });
    });

    $.ajax(
    {
        url: "updateGroupAccess.php",
        type: "POST",
        data:
        {
            moduleID: moduleID,
            chk: chk
        },
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function (jsonStr)
        {
            $("#btnUpdate").attr({disabled: true, value: "Update"}).addClass('btn_inact').removeClass('btn_act');;
        }
    });
});
```

If I put the AJAX function inside `.each` function it will submit more than 1.
But I need to put it outside, and found problem `moduleID` and `chk` not found.

Comment: declare it outside ,each where it is accessible to ajax

Comment: i.e. `$('#btnUpdate').click(function () {
  $('#result').html('');
  var chk = new Array();
  $('.moduleIDInput').each(function () {
   //
  });
 });`

Comment: can you pls add the html you are working

Answer (score 0):

Scope problem. Define `uid` and `moduleID` outside the click.

```
var uid="";
var moduleID="";
$('#btnUpdate').click(function()
{
    $('#result').html('');
    $('.moduleIDInput').each(function()
    {
         uid = $(this).attr('id');  // Assign value for uid 
         moduleID = $(this).val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the variables in the global scope:
make a function called sendAjax and call it on button click.
In the mean time all your data will be stored in the **data** global variable (object).

```
  var data={};
$('#btnUpdate').click(function()
{
    $('#result').html('');
    $('.moduleIDInput').each(function()
    {
        var uid = $(this).attr('id');
        data.moduleID = $(this).val();
        $('#result').append('<h3>' +$(this).val() + '</h3>');

        $('input[data-uid=' + uid + ']:checked').each(function()
        {
            data.chk.push($(this).val());

            $('#result').append('<div>'+ $(this).val() + '</div>');
        });
    });
  sendAjax();
});
  function sendAjax()
  {
          $.ajax(
    {
        url: "updateGroupAccess.php",
        type: "POST",
        data:
        {
            moduleID: data.moduleID,
            chk: data.chk
        },
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function (jsonStr)
        {
            $("#btnUpdate").attr({disabled: true, value: "Update"}).addClass('btn_inact').removeClass('btn_act');;
        }
    });

  }
```